# vue-chartjs load data from parent component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, chart.js, vue-chartjs

I have a component for a LineChart, here is the code :

```
<script>
  import { Line } from 'vue-chartjs'

  export default {
    extends: Line,
    props: ['data', 'options'],
    mounted () {
      this.renderChart(this.data, this.options)
    }
  }
</script>
```

I want to use this component in another one as I can affect data to `data` and `options` value of the component Chart.vue.

I'm new to VueJS and can't understand an example like that in vue-chartjs doc.

Here is my component that will be the parent one, and what I've done from now :

```
<template>
  <div class="dashboard">
    <chart></chart>
  </div>

</template>

<script>
  import Chart from '@/components/Chart'

  export default {
    name: 'DashBoard',
    components: {
      'chart': Chart
    },
    mounted () {},
    data () {
      return {
        datacollection: null
      }
    }
  }
</script>

<!-- Add "scoped" attribute to limit CSS to this component only -->
<style scoped>
</style>
```

Comment: your question is not clear. Does the chart work? if so, then what do you need it to do? if not then what errors do you see

Comment: It is not displaying the first time the page is loaded, and the chart is displayed when I refresh...

Comment: I've fixed it for the display of the chart when the page is loaded it was about an error from another component ! What I need to do is to populate the chart from my parent component

Answer (score 4):

Where does your data come from?
Your example code is weird, as you are not passing your data as props.

So no wonder, that nothing shows up.

You have to pass your `datacollection` to your chart component.

```
<chart :data="datacollection" />
```

And keep in mind, that if you are using an API your data will arrive async. So the component mounts, renders the chart but your data is not there. So you need to add a v-if to be sure that your api call is finished.